# Use scipy.stats.entropy in Tensorflow Graph

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, scipy, tensor, entropy

my goal is to calculate the distance between two probability density functions called p_distb and q_distb in the following code snippet. I try to this by utilizing Jensen-Shannon-divergence since it's symmetric and bounded, the necessary **entropy** function is imported from **scipy.stats**.

When I try to run the graph, the following error occurs:

*if len(qk) != len(pk):
TypeError: len() of unsized object*

Obviously, scipy.stats.entropy isn't able to cope with the **tensorflow tensors even though these are downwards-compatible** and should act like numpy arrays.

Does anyone out there have a solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot!!

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

i_dim = 8
j_dim = 8

input_dim = 201

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[i_dim*j_dim, input_dim]))

input_vector = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[input_dim,1]))

min_codebook_dist = []

for index in range(i_dim*j_dim):

    p_distb = tf.div(weights[index,:],tf.reduce_sum(weights[index,:]))
    p_distb = tf.reshape(p_distb, shape=[input_dim,])

    q_distb = tf.div(input_vector,tf.reduce_sum(input_vector))
    q_distb = tf.reshape(input_vector, shape=[input_dim,])

    m_distb = tf.div(tf.add(p_distb,q_distb),2)

    dist_pq = np.sqrt((entropy(p_distb[:], m_distb[:]) + entropy(q_distb[:], m_distb[:])) / 2)

    min_codebook_dist.append(dist_pq)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init_op)
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow tensors aren't downwards compatible with numpy arrays. You can try wrapping the call to scipy in a tf.py_func to call scipy.